# The game module "project name "could not be loaded. There may be an operating system error or module may not be properly setup

Tags: visual-c++, module, header-files, unreal-engine5

this problem occurs when i used UGroomComponent.h in my character class , after including the header file  and module in projectname.cs files .after restarting the visual studio i am facing this error while compiling the code .

**i tried this **

- I add necessary module "HairStrandsCore" in  .cs file
- i delete the intermediate and save files and binaries files
- then  i regenerated the visual studio files  and restart the code
- after that i faced the Niagara not include error but i solved this by including the Niagara in modules
- but after all this it didn't solve